# Objective C - how to hide youtube embed video title and share button

Tags: objective-c

i have following code but i am struggling to hire upper bar containing title and share button.

```
  videoHTML=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\
                   <iframe  width=\"300\" height=\"150\" src=\"%@\"  autohide=\"2\"  showinfo=\"0\" frameborder=\"0\"></iframe>", videoURL];
```

any help will be highly appreciated.

thanks

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Its not clear from your question/

Comment: Does the top bar not hide itself after a few seconds? I am using YouTube's official iOS player https://cocoapods.org/pods/youtube-ios-player-helper and it works fine. The title and share button do appear for a couple of seconds but then fade away.